# AWS S3 Content Metadata is not set in response

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In particular, the problem is with image and `"Content-Type: image/png"`.

I tried to upload image of .png type using different approaches:

1. "upload" using Admin Console for S3 with default upload options;
2. "upload" using Admin Console for S3 with explicit setting of content
   type in meta data details;
3. using https://github.com/pkgcloud library

All three save content with proper metadata, as displayed:

[image].
However, if you try to access it via S3 http link, `"Content-Type"` is not set.

There is a workaround, which does not seem to work always though: open Admin Console for S3 and press "Save".

Does it look like an issue with S3 metadata, or should something additional be done to make Metadata be properly added to response?

p.s. cross-posted here as well: https://forums.aws.amazon.com/thread.jspa?threadID=195391&tstart=0

Comment: S3 always returns the metadata, no configuration required.  The problem you describe sort of defies explanation from an S3 perspective, and if not coming down in responses, it should not show in the console, either.  Could you provide an example URL of an object that returns no `Content-Type:` response header?

Comment: Uploaded attached picture: https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s3-metadata-not-in-response/png-metadata.png So, console shows, response does not have it.

Comment: `Date: Tue, 14 Jul 2015 03:28:23 GMT`
`Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Jul 2015 03:14:51 GMT`
`ETag: "3d7c6e8060c395bb62000d33b2ff155f"`
`Accept-Ranges: bytes`
`Content-Type: image/png`
`Content-Length: 55445`

Comment: Possibly the problem is with your method of viewing the response headers?  Or you're looking at cached (by the browser or something in your network) headers?

Comment: Yes, just got them via curl and wget. And yes, it was a version cached by browser, which does not have all headers. I should have been a little bit more attentive there. Michael, thanks for your help!